# How do I trace this bitmap with JPEG artifacts?

Tags: vector, inkscape, jpg, image-trace

I'm attempting to trace the following bitmap:

[image: A real chill penguin]

[*Image by ACStewart from the web comic "Behind the GIFs"*](http://www.webtoons.com/en/comedy/behind-the-gifs/how-to-be-chill-acstuart/viewer?title_no=658&episode_no=18#)

As humans, we can clearly see this was originally a vector, and should trace well. The problem is, the JPEG artifacting is causing Inkscape's "Trace Bitmap" code to think the clear black line against the white background as having a gray strip and even a bit of blue running around it.

[image: Zoomed in result of Trace Bitmap in Inkscape]

Are there any settings to tweak or any way to trick Inkscape into seeing the lossy JPEG as the vector image it really is?

Comment: It's not the most complicated illustration in the world. Could you not trace it by hand using the pen tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The bad news:** With automatic tracing algorithms alone, you won't be able to get a clean result. There will always be noise.

**The good news:** If you're willing to invest just a bit of effort in manual cleanup, you can get a very decent vectorized reconstruction. This is what I was able to get in roughly 5 minutes:

[image: Original and Reconstructed]

*(Click on the image for a high-res version or jump straight to the SVG at the bottom.)*

Here's what I did:

1. Run **"Trace Bitmap"** on the original twice, once using **"Brightness Cutoff"** at **0.45** and once using **"Multiple scans: Colors"** with **6 scans**.

[image]

In the "Mode" tab, make sure the fields "Smooth", "Stack scans" and "Remove background" are all **unchecked**. These were my "Options" for both traces:

[image]

2. Put the result of the "Brightness Cutoff" on the side. It is actually really good and gives you all the blacks (as pointed out by [Juancho](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/73088/69077)). So all that's missing is the colored areas.
3. Separate the 6 color layers, delete the ones that contain just noise, **clean the remaining layers** until you're left with the missing big colored patches:

[image]

*Hint:* To delete the noise, enter "Node selection mode" (F2), select a bunch of noisy nodes by dragging a box around them and delete them with `Ctrl+Del`.

4. **Align the patches**. If some patches seem to have been "thinned out" slightly during tracing, you can "fatten them up" again with "Path" > "Outset" (or `Ctrl+)`). Finally, group the result.

And there you have your reconstructed SVG:

[image: reconstructed SVG]

Right-click and "Save image as..." on the above image or click [here](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/assets/content/HowToBeChill_vectorized.svg) to download the standalone SVG file.

Comment: I have been using just plain `DEL` for years, and often I get these "wacky" curves when I delete nodes. I am so happy you showed me `CTRL+DEL`: [_delete without preserving shape_](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys046.html#id2249656)

Comment: @IQAndreas Yep, `Ctrl+Del` is a pretty essential one ;-)
If my answer solves your question, do you mind accepting it?

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you think you could note which other settings you used? (for instance, it looks like _"Stack Scans"_ is disabled based on the results)

Comment: @IQAndreas Thanks for pointing that out, I just added the missing checkbox states to the answer. "Stack Scans" was in fact disabled. I just realized that with "Stack Scans" enabled, it is possibly even simpler to separate the colored patches. Oh, well - works either way ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you trace the bitmap with the *Brightness Cutoff* algorithm and threshold 0.3, you will get a nice rendering of the black strokes only.

This will get most of the job done.

Another trace with a higher cutoff will get you the whole head included. You can colour this second trace grey and layer it below the first black trace.

Comment: The first step got the blacks perfectly! Unfortunately, when I increased the brightness cutoff threshold, inkscape decided to include "the fuzzy JPEG border" outside of the black, so I still ended up with similar results to using multiple scans with 4/5 colors.